# WSO2 APIM Build Failure : : am-p2-profile: Cannot generate P2 metadata: P2 publisher return code was 13 -

Tags: maven, wso2, api-manager

Unable to build wso2 API manager version 2.6.0.

Os : Tried with Windows 10 and Cent OS

Maven & Java version Details:

[root@localhost ~]# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_242, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

maven build error:

```
[INFO] --- carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.4:materialize-product (creating-gateway-worker-profile)                                                           @ am-p2-profile ---
[INFO] Command line:
        /bin/sh -c cd /root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product && /u                                                          sr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/r                                                          epository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-p2-runtime/0.13.0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.                                                          launcher_1.2.0.v20110725-1610.jar -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director                                                           -metadataRepository file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/t                                                          arget/p2-repo -artifactRepository file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-prof                                                          ile/product/target/p2-repo -installIU carbon.product.id -profileProperties org.eclipse.u                                                          pdate.install.features=true -profile gateway-worker -bundlepool file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso                                                          2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/compo                                                          nents -shared file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/w                                                          so2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/components/p2 -destination file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-pr                                                          oduct-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/component                                                          s/gateway-worker -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86 -roaming
Installing carbon.product.id 4.4.35.
Installation failed.
One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation.
Application failed, log file location: /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-p2-r                                                          untime/0.13.0/eclipse/configuration/1586643837368.log

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Aggregator Module .............. SUCCESS [4.285s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles Parent .................. SUCCESS [0.295s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles ......................... SUCCESS [8.789s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - UI styles ............. SUCCESS [9.588s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Multi Tenant Dashboard ......... SUCCESS [4.142s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Features Parent ................ SUCCESS [0.126s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Features Aggregator Module ..... SUCCESS [0.102s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles Features ................ SUCCESS [1.729s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Multi Tenant Dashboard Feature . SUCCESS [4.649s]
[INFO] Samples ........................................... SUCCESS [2.094s]
[INFO] Clients for samples ............................... SUCCESS [0.409s]
[INFO] Publisher API client .............................. SUCCESS [12.008s]
[INFO] Store API client .................................. SUCCESS [4.289s]
[INFO] Admin API client .................................. SUCCESS [4.047s]
[INFO] Back end Service .................................. SUCCESS [7.122s]
[INFO] Sample Utils ...................................... SUCCESS [7.901s]
[INFO] Sample One ........................................ SUCCESS [47.254s]
[INFO] Sample Two ........................................ SUCCESS [28.712s]
[INFO] Sample Four ....................................... SUCCESS [29.776s]
[INFO] Sample Seven ...................................... SUCCESS [28.981s]
[INFO] Sample Eight ...................................... SUCCESS [30.187s]
[INFO] Sample Nine ....................................... SUCCESS [31.633s]
[INFO] Sample Ten ........................................ SUCCESS [31.590s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation Parent ... SUCCESS [0.096s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation .......... FAILURE [2:21.827s]
[INFO] API Manager : oauth2-grant-types .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Distribution Parent ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Distribution ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - API Import Export .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Tests .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Test Common Module . SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Admin Clients Module  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Common Test Module . SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Test Artifacts Tests ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - RestFul Backend Module for Integration Tests  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - ArtifactDeploymentMonitor WebApp  SKIPPED
[INFO] org.wso2.am.framework.extensions .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration Extensions Module .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration UI Pages Module .... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Integration New Test Module .... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Based on product backend Test Module  SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7:26.537s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Apr 11 18:24:10 EDT 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 81M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.4:materialize-product                                                           (creating-gateway-worker-profile) on project am-p2-profile: Cannot generate P2 metadata                                                          : P2 publisher return code was 13 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the fo                                                          llowing articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :am-p2-profile
```

LOG FROM  1586643837368.log

```
[root@localhost configuration]# cat 1586643837368.log
!SESSION 2020-04-11 18:23:56.569 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_242
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -metadataRepository file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepository file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -installIU carbon.product.id -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -profile gateway-worker -bundlepool file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/components -shared file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/components/p2 -destination file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/components/gateway-worker -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86 -roaming
Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -metadataRepository file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepository file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -installIU carbon.product.id -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -profile gateway-worker -bundlepool file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/components -shared file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/components/p2 -destination file:/root/wso2/APIM/wso2-product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.35/repository/components/gateway-worker -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86 -roaming

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 8 0 2020-04-11 18:24:09.869
!MESSAGE One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation.
[root@localhost configuration]# pwd
/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-p2-runtime/0.13.0/eclipse/configuration
[root@localhost configuration]# cat 1586643837368.log^C
[root@localhost configuration]#
```

Comment: Please add logs before and after above line.

Comment: Added complete log

Comment: Jar signature verification has failed due to missing CA cert in the Java cert store. `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/security/cacerts` file. Probably Java has stopped packaging that CA in later Java8 releases. You have to find the missing CA and install it using `keytool -import -file missingCA.crt -keystore cacerts`.

Comment: Try lowering the JDK versions or use Oracle JDK instead. If the build is a success with another version, then you can find the missing CA by listing each versions cacerts. `keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts`.